# Adding Button to Show Master View from Detail View

Tags: ios, master-detail, uisplitview

I am trying to add a button to my navigation bar on my detail view to show the master view when in portrait mode but the button isn't showing up.  Can anyone help or offer suggestions?

Here is how I was trying to do it in the detail view:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{
    mainMenu = barButtonItem;
    [mainMenu setTitle:@"Menu"];
    [[self navigationItem]setLeftBarButtonItem:mainMenu];
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    if (mainMenu == [[self navigationItem]leftBarButtonItem])
    {
        [[self navigationItem]setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm loading the detail view when selecting a row in my master view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    NSMutableArray *details = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

    UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:webViewController];

    [details replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:detailNav];

    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = details;

    KFBAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KFBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
```

I've added this to viewDidLoad and the button shows up now but I'm not sure how to get it to show the master view.

```
mainMenu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
    [mainMenu setTitle:@"Menu"];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = mainMenu;
```

Here is a picture of what it looks like when I swipe from the left to show the master view.

[image]

I've managed to get a left button to appear but now I don't know how to have it open the master view.  Here is how I got the button to show up:

```
mainMenu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
    [mainMenu setTitle:@"Menu"];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = mainMenu;
```

Comment: take a look at my edited answer please.

Comment: I already have a right bar button that shows an activity view

Comment: Also, I created this project from the master-detail template and haven't really altered much of that template code.  When in portrait I can show the master view by swiping from the left of the screen.

Comment: From the image you posted it seems that the right button is your share button. My assumption is that you place that button through IB. It covers the button that you are creating through code. Your button is being created but it hides under the share button. You may have to subclass a button and use CGRect to place it where you want it. Or just add another button through IB and by using flexible space arrows place it where you want it. Then declare the action through a IBAction and incorporate it in your autorotation method for Portrait. Or alternatively place your share button somewhere else.

Comment: The right button is added programmatically, not through IB.  I'm trying to add a left bar button.  I've gotten a left button to show up but I'm not sure how to make it open the master view.

Comment: In that case just use an ibaction method to open the master. The code should be similar to what comes generically with a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than left button, use right bar button and it will show. The problem is the button on the left gets hidden by the default button of the vavigation controller. Try the right bar button.

**Edit**

This is a generic method that is placed in view did load to include a right bar button. then you can access is in other methods. hope it helps.

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
```

In here insert new object in the selector is the `IBAction` that you use to declare what that button has to do.

Comment: Have you tried self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem; that might be the issue

Comment: I put this in my viewDidLoad method:

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = mainMenu;

Comment: you can or replace the method in will hide and will show and see if you can invoke the button.

Comment: I've tried putting self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = mainMenu; in willHide and willShow as well as viewDidLoad with no luck.